# Default Radio button selected value

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

In the following code how do I make sure **that the Default radio button selected is always
Period** ?? Currently when the page is loaded , non is selected in the radio button.

```
<tr>
    <th valign="top" align="left">
        Scope 
        <span class="required">*</span>
    </th>
    <td align="left">
        <p class="error-message" id="span_scopeType"></p>
        <s:radio name="scopeType" id="scopeType" list="#{'PERIOD':'Period','MONTH':'Month','CUSTOM':' Custom'}" value="%{scopeType}" onchange="loadReport(this)"></s:radio>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML input type radio has a "checked" attribute, you can use this so that on load a specific option is checked.

```
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="male">Male<br>
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="female" checked="checked">Female
```

I hope this resolves your issue.

Further information: [HTML DOM Object: Radio Button](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_radio.asp)

Comment: You should not cite w3fools.com as a source of information; see http://w3fools.com

Comment: Perhaps, though it showed the necessary information for Amit. I did not need to use the resource though it helps to back-up my point. 

Any recommendations on a good place to cite?

Never mind I see the second on the website with reputable sources. They make some good points such as "W3 should Wikify their content". I +1 that!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in through angular2

```js
class onInitRadio {
  selected = {"value":"X"};
}
```

```html
<md-radio-group class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selected.value" 
                id="radioGroup" formControlName="selected">
  <md-radio-button [value]="'X'">X</md-radio-button>
  <md-radio-button [value]="'Y'">Y</md-radio-button>
</md-radio-group>
```